# Can't get GCM Registration Id for devices below 4.1

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM in my application and the following code is working for devices above 4.1.

However, for devices below 4.1 I can't seem to get GCM Registration ID.

Please anyone give me the solution why this is happening.

This is the code I'm using to get the regId.

```
    checkNotNull(CommonUtils.SENDER_ID, "SENDER_ID");
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar
            .getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext());
    Log.i(TAG + ">>>>>>>>....", "R Id Is>>>>>>" + regId);
    if (regId.equals("")) {
        // Automatically registers application on startup.
        GCMRegistrar.register(getApplicationContext(),
                CommonUtils.SENDER_ID);

    } else {
        Log.i(TAG + ">>>>>>>>....", "Already Registered");

    }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: where you have tested in mobile phone or emulator?

Comment: I am facing the same problem - it is working on my emulator but can't get the registration id while running on the device.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a setup google account in the device the GCM Registration Id won't be fetch.

Please make sure you have it.

Comment: This is a question to the OP and must be a comment. Not an answer. Please consider removing it.

Comment: Thank you. corrected it because i'm pretty sure this must be probably the issue.

Comment: Yes I have google accounts . I got the register Id from those devices.But now I am facing problem that the device regIds are not getting for some devices. previously i got the regId for the same devices with same implementation. Now I have changed the Sender Id and server key for my new application.

Comment: and you are logged in on that device?

Comment: I also have Google account on my device (logged in) and still can't get a registration ID. Any suggestions ? On the Other hand it is working on my emulator...